# Creating JSON in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json, stringify

How should I encode this data as JSON in javascript?

I use javascript to get an arbitrary number of 'tags' on photos. Each tag has a firstname and a lastname in this form:

```
firstname = 'john';
lastname  = 'doe';

firstname = 'jane';
lastname  = 'smith';
```

I want to encode this data as JSON, send it to my server with Ajax, and decode it in PHP.

My thought was to create a multidimensional array. Is there a better way to do this?

The output of JSON.stringify() is `[{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\"},{\"firstname\":\"Jane\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}]`. How can I have JSON.stringify() not escape all of the quotes?

Comment: Unless youre using an API the requires you to send a request in JSON its much easier just send a standard post to the server.

Comment: I'm using FormData, so unfortunately it has to be sent as JSON

Comment: Not sure what `FormData` is... is that a .Net thing?

Comment: Curious, you've tagged the question as [json] and [stringify] but apparently `JSON.stringify()` is the one thing you've not tried.

Comment: I was trying JSON.stringify(), and it seems to format my data incorrectly, so I figured I'd check here.

Comment: That's an interesting bit of information that really should have made it into the question. What incorrect format did you see?

Comment: The result I end up with is [{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"firstname":"Jane","lastname":"Smith"}], and it seems that PHP's json_decode can't get a result out of this

Comment: It does work. I just checked it with your string. Perhaps you aren't wrapping it with single quotes? Check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON is inspired by JavaScript's object syntax, so all you need to do is create an array of objects:

```
var data = [
  {
    firstname: 'john',
    lastname: 'doe'
  },
  {
    firstname: 'jane',
    lastname: 'smith'
  }
]

var json = JSON.stringify( data ); // send this object to server
```

Comment: Note: JSON.stringify/JSON.parse require a shim on IE7 (ick!) and before.

Comment: When I do this I end up with [{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"firstname":"Jane","lastname":"Smith"}], and it seems that PHP's json_decode can't get a result out of this

Comment: The output of JSON.stringify() is [{\"firstname\":\"John\",\"lastname\":\"Doe\"},{\"firstname\":\"Jane\",\"lastname\":\"Smith\"}]. How can I have JSON.stringify() not escape all of the quotes?

Answer (score 1):

JSON is the way to go

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
 var data = [{
    firstname: 'john',
    lastname: 'doe'
    },
    {
    firstname: 'jane',
    lastname: 'smith'
   }
 ]

var json = JSON.stringify( data );
```

Now your JSON string will be

> [{"firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"firstname":"Jane","lastname":"Smith"}]

**PHP**

```
$arr=json_decode('$jsonVar');
```

Make sure you put the single quotes cover on the php side. Otherwise PHP won't read this as a string

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't have to wrap it in single quotes. Why would you need to do this? It's supposed to be evaluating the value of the variable, not reading the string.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your tags into json object

```
var jsonObj = '{"TeamList" : [{"teamid" : "1","teamname" : "Barcelona"}]}';
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```

or

```
 var jsonObj = {
"employees": [
{ "firstName":"John" , "lastName":"Doe" }, 
{ "firstName":"Anna" , "lastName":"Smith" }, 
{ "firstName":"Peter" , "lastName":"Jones" }
]
}
var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonObj);
```